Find unescaped line breaks from middle of RFC4180 CSV
I am writing parsing logic for an RFC4180 csv file.
I am wondering if it is possible to seek to an arbitrary position in the file, then scan either forwards or backwards to the nearest unescaped line break.
The issue is that after the initial seek I have no way of knowing whether I have landed within a quoted field or not, so when scanning forwards or backwards I don't know whether line breaks I encounter are actually line-breaks or escaped line breaks within the field.
I'd like a solution to work with arbitrary RFC4180 files and don't want to rewrite with all quoted fields. I'd also like not to implement a maximum_field_length solution where I would limit my scanning to this value.
Is this possible or do you just need the context from the start of the file?
Thanks

I'd say CSV is not random access: you have to start at the beginning to understand the context of any token-looking-thing your parser inspects thereafter. I'm thinking of the pathological case of valid CSV being encoded as a single value in a field.

If you go to the bottom of RFC4180 and follow link for the Informative References, 'Raymond, E., "The Art of Unix Programming"...', and start reading at, 'In fact, the Microsoft version of CSV is a textbook example of how not to design a textual file format.', I think you can take those arguments as evidence you cannot do what you asked.
